# ¿Como añadir funciones de javascript en angular 8?

Tags: javascript, angular

estoy migrando un pequeño proyecto a Angular 8 en el que uso javascript para hacer ciertos cálculos y mostrárselos al usuario:

Ejemplo:

```
function suma(){
    a = document.getElementById("valorA").value;
    b = document.getElementById("valorB").value;
    c = a + b;
    document.getElementById("posicion").innerHTML = c
}
```

Los cálculos son muchos más y más complejos que eso, y cada página o componente en este caso tiene su propia lógica detrás, he visto soluciones como cargar los scripts en el index.html, sin embargo no me parece una opción adecuada al tener tantos scripts diferentes.

Comment: Favor incluye código suficiente para permitir a otros reproducir el problema

Answer (score 1):

En Angular no necesitas usar funciones para una tarea tan sencilla como esa. Basta con usar el siguiente HTML en tu componente:

```
<div>
  A: <input [(ngModel)]="a" /><br />
  B: <input [(ngModel)]="b" /><br />
  A+B: <input [ngModel]="(a-0) + (b-0)" />
</div>
```

Como no se puede usar `parseInt()` en `ngModel` he de forzar la conversión a números mediante una resta.

---

Si deseas usar una función para ello, eres libre de hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
<div>
  A: <input [(ngModel)]="a" /><br />
  B: <input [(ngModel)]="b" /><br />
  <button (click)="suma()">Sumar</button><br />
  Resultado: <input [ngModel]="c" />
</div>
```

Declarando la función en tu componente así:

```
export class AppComponent {
  /* Propiedades de la clase */
  a: string = "0";
  b: string = "0";
  c: string = "0";
  /* Método de la clase que realizará la suma */
  suma() {
    /* Asignamos como cadena a "c" la suma de enteros de "a + b" */
    this.c = String(parseInt(this.a) + parseInt(this.b));
  }
}
```

Debido a los tipos de datos estrictos de TypeScript, debes convertir en cadena el resultado de la suma mediante [`String()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) y las cadenas de cada campo del formulario mediante [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

Puedes verlo funcionando en línea en el siguiente enlace:

- https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-dirac-7ke03?file=/src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

No deberías utilizar `document.getElementById`, deberias usar el data binding.

En tu `.ts` puedes colocar algo como:

```
export class AppComponent {
  sumaTotal = 0;

  suma(){
    a = 14;
    b = 2;
    this.sumaTotal = a + b;
  }

}
```

y en tu `.html`

```
<div> {{ suma() }} </div>
```